# Open a new link in an if statement with PHP

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I have the 'else if' statement below, and I want to open a new page in my host (main.html), if the entry password  is correct.

```
<?php
$var1="1";
$pass=$_POST['password'];
if ($pass==$var1) 
{
echo "ok";

 //***here is your help***

}  

elseif ($pass=="")
{echo "No Entry";
}
else { echo "Wrong Password";}

?>
```

Please suggest a PHP code for opening a new window.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php This one  is help

Comment: use header("location:main.html") after condition satisfy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP won't be able to handle opening a new window for you. The most you can do is a redirection.

```
header('Location: http://destination.com');
```

Opening a new window can be done with JavaScript

```
window.open('http://destination.com');
```

Comment: thank you all.
the header function works.

but I want to open it in a new window or tab.
russellc said i should use javascript.

i'm going to work on it 
thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Location: http://host/'.[your new page]);
exit;
```

Comment: upvote: using exit after `header('Location : ...');` is the best practise!

Answer (score 2):

you may use

```
header("location:pagename.php");
```

Open in new window

```
window.open('pagename.php');
```

Comment: thank you all
the header function works

but I want to open it in a new window or tab
russellc said I should use javascript . i'm going to work on it
i will ask you again if it dosn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use header to redirect:

```
<?php
    $var1="1";
    $pass=$_POST['password'];
    if ($pass==$var1) 
    {
        echo "ok";
        header('Location: main.html');
        exit;
    } 
    elseif ($pass=="")
    {
        echo "No Entry";
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo "Wrong Password";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Window.open('link') will block the URL by default.

Try using pure JS:

```
echo "<script>  Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { target: '_blank', href: '{$URL}'}).click(); </script>" ;
```

It creates a virtual `a` element, gives it `target="_blank"` so it opens in a new tab, gives it proper `url` `href` and then clicks it.